# Direct to Reported Speech - a scenario of ambiguity

Tags: indirect-speech

The question is:

How would one convert

> He said, "My name is Harry"

to reported speech?

Rules do say that the converted sentence reads

> He said that his name was Harry.

The factor causing discomfort is the 'was' part of it. So it means that his name 'was' Harry and nothing is said about what his name 'is'! So there is a radical change in meaning!! In that light, the converted sentence should read

> He said that his name is Harry.

Isn't the latter the correct conversion?

Comment: Those are the rules, and this is what native English speakers do by default. Consider [this Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He+said+his+name+is%2C+He+said+his+name+was&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=). There are indeed times when you don't backshift; namely, when you want to emphasize that the statement still is true. For example, maybe in the sentence "He said that God is good". See [this Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He+said+that+God+is%2CHe+said+that+God+was&year_start=1850&year_end=2009&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

Comment: The difficulty is the presumption that there must be one and only one Correct way to say something. This is **not** ambiguity -- they both mean exactly the same thing. On the contrary, this is variety. Clearly, there is more than one Correct way, and neither of these two is more Correct than the other.

Comment: Personally, I'd leave out the "that."  Simpler:  He said his name is Harry.  I also agree with John Lawler and say, "Rules, schmools!"

Comment: This is a duplicate of many, many questions. Start from the question this has been closed as a duplicate of, and work your way up from there by following the Related links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having looked at the site that @bigbadonk420 referred to in his answer, I disagree with that answer and interpretation of the quoted site. On my reading of that site, the two options for reported speech are (using the OP's quotation):

> with backshift: *He **said** that his name **was** Harry*
>   without backshift: *He **says** that his name **is** Harry*

There is no suggestion that you can mix the two, which suggests that

> *He **said** that his name **is** Harry*

is incorrect, or at least not normal usage, as also confirmed by the first Ngram mentioned by @PeterShore

Comment: "Says his name is Harry!" not "Said that his name is Harry!" Thanks for pointing out, for in the latter the tense is not consistent, past and present mixed!

Answer (score 1):

The default rule in English is indeed to backshift when you use past tense for reported speech. For example, see [this Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He+said+his+name+is%2C+He+said+his+name+was&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), which shows that "He said his name was" is around 20 times as common as "He said his name is".

On the other hand, if you want to ***emphasize*** the fact that the statement is still true, then you can indeed use the present tense with "He said that ...". For example, if somebody said "God is real", I would be likely to quote him by saying

> He said that God is real.

See [this Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He+said+that+God+is%2CHe+said+that+God+was&year_start=1850&year_end=2009&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), which shows that "He said that God was" is only around twice as common as "He said that God is".